# Arshaw fullcalendar js display time only once for each hour

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

i am trying to create my arshaw fullcalendar to like the following image 
[image: how i want it to look]

it is working only for 15 or 30 minutes slot duration, but i want it to work with any duration.
and here is how it does look if i put 10 minutes slot duration

[image: how it is looking now]

does anyone have a solution for that ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: solution for what exactly? It's not at all clear what you mean. You say "it is working", but what is "it"? Presumably in that first screenshot you had set `slotDuration: "00:15:00",
        slotLabelInterval: "01:00:00",`? And in the second one you simply had set simply `slotDuration: "00:10:00"`? So there is a clear difference between them in terms of the settings used. How were you expecting / hoping the second one to appear? What is the rule you want to apply to "any duration"? Again it's totally unclear what the actual problem is you are trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry because it is not clear, i want the time axis to show the time only once for first 6 slots ( when i put slot duration 10 ) . Exactly like in the first screen ( each hour show only one time ).i fixed it by changing the if statement inside the fullcalendar script

Comment: for that you can set `slotLabelInterval`.